# x.string Unhandled exception at 0x0014A25D

Tags: c++, visual-studio, glfw, glew

I am using Visual 2019 with Visual C++. I was following the tutorial by The Cherno. I am stuck on the end of the Eight Episode. What is causing this?

main.cpp:

```
#include <gl/glew.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>

struct ShaderProgramSources
{
    std::string VertexSource;
    std::string FragmentSource;
};
static ShaderProgramSources ParseShader(const std::string& filepath)
{
    std::ifstream stream(filepath);

    enum class shaderType {
        NONE = -1, VERTEX = 0, FRAGMENT = 1
    };

    std::string line;
    std::stringstream ss[1];;

    shaderType type = shaderType::NONE;

    while (getline(stream, line))
    {
        if (line.find("#shader") != std::string::npos)
        {

            if (line.find("vertex") != std::string::npos)
            
                shaderType type = shaderType::VERTEX;

            else if (line.find("fragment") != std::string::npos)
                
                shaderType type = shaderType::FRAGMENT;
            }

        else
        {
            ss[(int)type] << line << "\n";
        }
        }
    return { ss[0].str(), ss[1].str() };
}
static unsigned int CompileShader(unsigned int type, const std::string& source)
{
    unsigned int id = glCreateShader(type);
    const char* src = source.c_str();
    glShaderSource(id, 1, &src, nullptr);
    glCompileShader(id);

    int result;
    
    glGetShaderiv(id, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &result);
        if (result = GL_FALSE) 
        {
            int legnth;
            glGetShaderiv(id, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &legnth);
            char* message = (char*)alloca(legnth * sizeof(char));
            glGetShaderInfoLog(id, legnth, &legnth, message);
            std::cout << "Failed to Compile" << (type == GL_VERTEX_SHADER ? "Vertex: Shader:\n" : "Fragment Shader:\n");
            glDeleteShader(id);
            
            return 0;
        }

    return id;
}

static unsigned int CreateShader(const std::string& vertexShader, const std::string& fragmentShader) 
{
    unsigned int program = glCreateProgram();
    unsigned int vs = CompileShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER, vertexShader);
    unsigned int fs = CompileShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, fragmentShader);
    glAttachShader(program, vs);
    glAttachShader(program, fs);
    glLinkProgram(program);
    glValidateProgram(program);

    return program;
}

int main(void)
{
    GLFWwindow* window;
    if (!glewInit())
        return -1;

    /* Initialize the library */
    if (!glfwInit())
        return -1;

    window = glfwCreateWindow(640, 480, "Cooked Pixel", NULL, NULL);
    if (!window)
    {
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }
    
    /* Make the window's context current */
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

    if (glewInit() != GLEW_OK) 
    {
        std::cout << "Error: GLEW is not initialized \n";
    }

    std::cout << "GL Version: " << glGetString(GL_VERSION) << "\n";
    
    float positions[6] = {
     -0.5, -0.5,
     0.0, -0.5,
     0.5, 0.5
    };
    unsigned int buffer;
    glGenBuffers(1, &buffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 6 * sizeof(float), positions, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(float) * 2, 0);
    
    std::string vertexShader = R"glsl(
    #version 330 core
    layout(location = 0) in vec4 position;
    void main()
    {
        gl_Position = position;
    }
        
    )glsl";

    std::string fragmentShader = R"glsl(
    #version 330 core
    layout(location = 0) out vec4 color;
    void main()
    {
        color = vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    }
        
    )glsl";

    ShaderProgramSources source = ParseShader("res/shaders/basic.shader");
    std::cout << source.FragmentSource << "\n";
    std::cout << source.VertexSource << "\n";
    unsigned int shader = CreateShader(vertexShader, fragmentShader);
    glUseProgram(shader);

    glfwMaximizeWindow(window);
    /* Loop until the user closes the window */
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);

        glfwSwapBuffers(window);

        glfwPollEvents();
}

    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}
```

I get the error on x.string line 433 as:

> Unhandled exception at 0x00CEA25D in CookedPixel.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xCCCCCCD0. occurred

Comment: Pleae post code as part of the question, not as external link.  See also [ask].

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access memory which hasn't been initialized yet or there is an out-of-bound memory error. For more [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30998231/access-violation-reading-location-visual-studio-c) [link2](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/1f850f9e-41fd-4178-9da5-a0f568051309/unhandled-exception-at-access-violation-reading-location-?forum=vclanguage). Anyway, I see there's only 178 line in the referred cpp file, not sure how you got the error on line 433.

Answer (score 0):

You have at least one error. It will become very obvious when you closely look at `ParseShader`. You declare a variable

```
std::stringstream ss[1];
```

That's an array with just one element. Later you access it like this:

```
ss[(int)type] << line << "\n";
```

This will cause undefined behavior (that can manifest as crash) when `(int)type` is anything but `0`. At then end you get UB anyway:

```
return { ss[0].str(), ss[1].str() };
```

is an obvious out-of-bounds access.

However, that's just from first glance. This seems like a good time to learn [What a debugger is and how it can help you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems). Using a debugger is a very important skill.